# d3 Google map from local json variable

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm adding map markers on google map using d3.js.

My problem is that when I load JSON data via an API URL that returns JSON -- it works
but when I have the JSON in a local variable I get `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

[image: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined error]

[image: my code]

Here is my code:

```
    var MYDATA = "http://localhost:8080/Scripts/maps/example.json" // this will work perfectly
    var MYDATA = dataJson // this does not work, error: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    d3.json(MYDATA, function (error, res, json) {
    res.data.result_list.forEach(function (o, i) {...}
```

**Note:** both **dataJson** and **example.json** contains the exact same JSON data

am I missing something here?

Comment: 1. What version of d3 are you using? `d3.json(url, function)` was deprecated in v5 and removed in v6 in favour of `d3.json(url).then(function)`; 2. Please add your code as a runnable [mre], never add code as pictures, as it's generally not very helpful. See also [ask]!

Comment: What does `dataJson` point to? The request to whatever is in `dataJson` results in an error leaving `res` as `undefined`, hence, the error "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined". You need to find out what's wrong with the request. Plus, it's always a good idea to implement a proper error handling, i.e. evaluate the `error` parameter.